# I want to change random numbers from the list of them to the minimal meaning of list

Tags: python

I create a list of 'a' random numbers. And than I need to change odd numbers to the minimum number of this list. but it doesn't change any number, what's wrong?

```
import random

a = int(input('Num -> '))
s = []
for i in range(a):
    s.append(random.randint(0,10))
    if s[i]%2!=0:
        s[i]=min(s)
```

Comment: Could you please restate your question? At least for me it's not clear what you want

Comment: not sure I understand what you want as your output. But when I run through it with debugger, it does change the current value/number to what ever the minimum value is at that particular moment in your list `s`.

Comment: I create a list of 'a' random numbers. And than I need to change odd numbers to the minimum number of this list

Comment: you need to separate your loops. also, your code is changing the even numbers

Comment: Yoo meant to create second loop to change odd to min?

Comment: yes (see below). as you currently have it, it puts a random number in your list 1 at a time, then checks, then changes it to whatever the min is at that particular moment. Unless that's how you want it to work, but you stated you create a list of 'a' random numbers first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed `if s[i]%2==0` to `if s[i]%2!=0` to pick out the odd numbers. The first way will change even numbers

```
import random

a = int(input('Num -> '))

# creates your list of x random numbers
s = []
for i in range(a):
    s.append(random.randint(0,10))


# change odd numbers to the min of the original list    
for i in range(a):    
    if s[i]%2!=0:
        s[i]=min(s)
```

so let's say a is 10:

```
>>> [2, 2, 8, 1, 2, 2, 10, 7, 5, 7]
```

now change all odd numbers to min (in this case it's '1')

```
>>> [2, 2, 8, 1, 2, 2, 10, 1, 1, 1]
```

The answer below works too, it's just a matter of if you need it to change after each iteration of creating the list, or create the list first, and then apply your rule.

Answer (score 1):

You program does, indeed, change the numbers as you requested.  I added trivial `print` statements to track this:

import random

```
a = 10
s = []
for i in range(a):
    s.append(random.randint(0,10))
    if s[i]%2==0:
        print("Changing", i)
        print("\tbefore", s)
        s[i]=min(s)
        print("\t after", s)
```

Output:

```
Changing 1
    before [3, 10]
     after [3, 3]
Changing 6
    before [3, 3, 5, 9, 9, 1, 8]
     after [3, 3, 5, 9, 9, 1, 1]
Changing 7
    before [3, 3, 5, 9, 9, 1, 1, 6]
     after [3, 3, 5, 9, 9, 1, 1, 1]
Changing 8
    before [3, 3, 5, 9, 9, 1, 1, 1, 6]
     after [3, 3, 5, 9, 9, 1, 1, 1, 1]
Changing 9
    before [3, 3, 5, 9, 9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
     after [3, 3, 5, 9, 9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

As you can see, the even numbers *do* get replaced with the list minimum.  Your claim that it doesn't change any number is incorrect.

If you want to change *odd* numbers, then you need to invert your check:

```
if s[i]%2 == 1:
```

Comment: this code didn't work, I had next output: Changing 1
 before [9, 4]
  after [9, 4]
Changing 3
 before [9, 4, 3, 10]
  after [9, 4, 3, 3]
Changing 5
 before [9, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4]
  after [9, 4, 3, 3, 5, 3]
Changing 6
 before [9, 4, 3, 3, 5, 3, 8]
  after [9, 4, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3]
Changing 7
 before [9, 4, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 6]
  after [9, 4, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3]
Changing 9
 before [9, 4, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 9, 4]
  after [9, 4, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 9, 3]

Comment: You need to *specify* how it fails.  As per your posting, this takes each odd number of the list and replaces it with the list minimum up to that point.  The output in your comment *does* operate in that fashion.  If you want something else, you need to specify that in your posting.